# The Configuration for physical path can not be opened

Tags: c#, .net, iis, encryption, rsa

I am trying to encrypt my `web.config` file connectionstring details but getting error as

```
The configuration for physical path "Path Goes Here" can not be opened
```

Here is the command that is being executed in Visual Studio Command prompt.

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef “connectionStrings” “C:\Users\Shi\Documents\ProjFolder\StudentApp\StudentApp” -prov "StudentProvider"
```

P.S: I have given write permission on the path and folder to everyone.
What is wrong in the command?

Comment: Are you running the command prompt as an administrator?

Comment: @Teja Yes........

Comment: Did you try running the command from the developer command prompt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [encrypting web.config failed error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035342/encrypting-web-config-failed-error)

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, I am trying from the developer command prompt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aspnet_regiis -pe "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication" -prov "RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider"
```

If the application is already hosted on IIS, this is the way to do it.  -site option can also be specified.

Make sure you have RSA key containers. Better idea is to implement it in the code so that encryption takes place when the app is called for the first time. There are many ways to do it in code.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.rsaprotectedconfigurationprovider.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Now the Physical path issue is gone but it is not able to find out the protection provider. any thoughts ?

Comment: You need to get RSA key containers in your machine. Follow this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w117ede.aspx

Comment: Also, if you are decrypting a config file which's encrypted on another machine, that doesn't work! Encryption and decryption has to happen on the same machine.

Comment: I tried to follow the link still not able to find protection provider